# How to overlay one video on another and then if one video finishes then fullscreen the other video [FFMPEG]

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

`ffmpeg -i s2.mp4 -vf "movie=s1small.mp4 [inner];[in][inner] overlay=100:100 [out]" merge.mp4`

**s1 dimension: 420x320**

**s2 dimension: 1280x720**

I want the other video to fullscreen if one video ends.

Comment: Too vague. "fullscreen" is a term applied to your player. Do you mean you want the s1 overlay to fit fully within the 1280x720 size of s2 once s2 ends?

Comment: Yes. If s2 gets finished first then  s1 dimension should increase to 1280x720. And if s1 gets finished first then just close s1 .s2 is already fullscreen.